# How to break a nested Python for-loop into many individual jobs and then run them on HTCondor?

Tags: parallel-processing, batch-processing, htcondor

I have a nested for loop with this kind of logic:

```
As, Bs, Cs = [...], [...], [...]
for a in As:
    for b in Bs:
        for c in Cs:
            result = function(a, b, c)
```

I want to break this into many HTCondor jobs, where each one takes an a, b, c value until every combination has been complete (which is what the nested for loop is doing). How can I do this using HTCondor?

I have tried writing different job scripts but they all just complete immediately with no output. I have also tried using HTmap however this gives a pile of Docker errors.